# What do coefficients of auto.arima mean?

Tags: r, arima

After running my auto.arima model I'm getting coefficients ar1, ar2 & sar1. What do these coefficients mean?

Answer (score 3):

The ar1 and ar2 coefficients are autoregressive coefficients of orders 1 and 2. The sar1 coefficient is a *seasonal* autoregressive coefficient of order 1.

You can read all about seasonal ARIMA models [in this section](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9) of [this excellent free online forecasting textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/). If you are not familiar with nonseasonal ARIMA, it would make sense to read the entire [chapter on ARIMA models](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9).