# ARIMA equation formation

Tags: arima

I have been generate the ARIMA using R software and getting the result, but I don't know how to write the equation.
[image]

How should I do? Thank you.

Comment: post your data ..... and I will try and help you .

Answer (score 1):

You have an ARIMA(3,2,3) model. This means that the second order differences (that is the middle "2") follow an ARMA(3,3) process.

We use the backshift operator $B$,

$$ By_t := y_t-y_{t-1}. $$

Here, you need the second order backshift,

$$ B^2y_t = B(y_t-y_{t-1}) = By_t-By_{t-1} = (y_t-y_{t-1}) - (y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}) = y_t-2y_{t-1}+y_{t-2}. $$

R's convention for ARIMA models mean that your model is

$$ B^2y_t = \phi_1B^2y_{t-1} + \phi_2B^2y_{t-2} + \phi_3B^2y_{t-3} + e_t + \theta_1e_{t-1} + \theta_2e_{t-2} + \theta_3e_{t-3}, $$

where the $\phi_i$ are your `ar` coefficients, $\theta_i$ are your `ma` coefficients, and $e_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, where you can read the estimate for $\sigma^2$ off in your output.

Yes, writing all this out and collection all the $y_{t-i}$ is tedious.

Similar questions and links can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224380/1352) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/360133/1352) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221160/1352).

Comment: Is that normal for the sigma^2 is so big?

Comment: It depends on the scale of your time series. If you are modeling rare sales, then it is high. If you are modeling the population of a city, it makes sense. Compare it to the raw variance of your data, which should yield a larger value.